# How to read a Bunch of files in a directory in lua

Tags: file-io, lua, torch

I have a path (as a string) to a directory. In that directory, are a bunch of text files. I want to go to that directory open it, and go to each text file and read the data.

I've tried

```
f = io.open(path)
f:read("*a")
```

I get the error "nil    Is a directory"

I've tried:

```
f = io.popen(path)
```

I get the error: "Permission denied"

Is it just me, but it seems to be a lot harder than it should be to do basic file io in lua?

Comment: relevant [List a directory in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303174/get-list-of-directory-in-a-lua)

Answer (score 4):

A directory isn't a file. You can't just open it.

And yes, lua itself has (intentionally) limited functionality.

You can use [luafilesystem](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/) or [luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) and similar modules to get more features in this area.

Comment: Yes, a directory isn't just a file. But if you have a directory A that has a list of directories B_i and you want to open all the files in directory B_i and all you have is a path to directory A, it seems that there should be an easy way to do this.

Comment: There is, mostly, when you have access to functions that support operations on directories. lua doesn't have those by default (for portability reasons).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following script to list the names of the files in a given directory (assuming Unix/Posix):

```
dirname = '.'
f = io.popen('ls ' .. dirname)
for name in f:lines() do print(name) end
```

Comment: I would use `io.popen('/bin/ls ' .. dirname)` to make sure no one tricks our application into executing the first `ls` they happened to put on the PATH.