# how to use lua to get all files from desktop

Tags: lua, love2d

I am making a project with lua that gets a list of all the file names from your desktop in lua. however, I can't figure out how to do it, and I am also going to be using love2d for it, because it is going to be a game. can you tell me how to do it? thanks!

Here is the code

```
function love.load()
  require "player"

  -- Lets add Some Variables!
  -- Some Directory Suff first for Variables...
  DesktopDirectory = love.filesystem.getUserDirectory().."Desktop"
  DesktopFiles = love.filesystem.getDirectoryItems(DesktopDirectory)

  -- These are the Images!
  images = {
    background = love.graphics.newImage("gfx/desktop.png")
  }

  players = {Player.New(50, 300, 40, 40, "gfx/stickman.png", true)}

  love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(100, 220, 255)

  for k in pairs(DesktopFiles) do
    print(DesktopFiles[k])
  end
end

function love.keypressed(k)
  if k == "j" then
    players[1].jump()
  end
end

function love.update(dt)
  for i in pairs(players) do
    players[i].update()
  end
end

function love.draw()
  love.graphics.draw(images.background)

  for i in pairs(players) do
    players[i].draw()
  end
end
```

Comment: what do you mean with "access the files from your desktop"? do you just want a list of those files?

Comment: pretty much yes... I meant to say "get a list of all the file names from your desktop"... let me rephrase that in the question!

Comment: there is a lot of information online on how to get file lists in lua. read this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303174/how-to-get-list-of-directories-in-lua

Answer (score 3):

Love2D (tries to) sandbox file system access, you're not supposed to touch anything outside your game's code or the "save directory" (where anything that you write goes).  In particular, the Desktop folder is also out of reach.  If you try to use `love.filesystem.getDirectoryItems` on that path, you'll just get an empty table.  Same for other functions – they'll just refuse to work.

The easiest way to get that functionality is to include [`lfs`](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/) and use its functions together with Lua's base [`io`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.7) library for general file system access.

Comment: thanks! let me try that out! but how do you use it though? like how to set it up?

Comment: See the question/answers linked by Piglet in the comment above. (You can also look at the right column, under the heading 'Linked'.)

Comment: (Or if you mean installing, try luarocks?)