# Search a file inside n number of sub folder using LUA script

Tags: lua, lua-scripting-library

I want to Search a file inside n number of sub folder (in windows environment).
Then copy that file and place in destination folder.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "search a file inside n number of sub folder". I'm guessing you are recursively looking for files in sub-directories with a max recursion depth of `n`?

I don't know lua, but if you can list the files in one directory (like with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5303802/1115876) then it should just be a simple matter of something like:

```
def search(dir, max_depth):
  if max_depth == 0: return
  for file in dir:
      if file is file:
        # do something
      if file is directory:
        search(file, max_depth - 1)
    
```

Comment: Are folders listed in array `{"C:\\Folder1", "D:\\Folder2"}` or you're searching in subfolders of a single folder?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff No.. It is not listed in array.. And i want to do it in lua script

Comment: @Snehasish - Do you need to recursively search in subfolders?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes

Answer (score 2):

```
function search_and_copy(filename, src_folder, dest_folder)
   local pipe = io.popen("reg query HKLM\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Nls\\CodePage /v ACP 2>nul:")
   local acp = pipe:read("*a"):match"ACP%s+REG_SZ%s+(%d+)"
   pipe:close()

   local function search_recursively(path)
      local src_filespec = path..filename
      local file = io.open(src_filespec)
      if file then
         file:close()
         return src_filespec
      end
      local subfolders = {}
      local pipe = io.popen((acp and 'chcp '..acp..'|' or '')..'dir /b/ad "' ..path..'*.*" 2>nul:')
      for line in pipe:lines() do
         table.insert(subfolders, line)
      end
      pipe:close()
      for _, subfolder_name in ipairs(subfolders) do
         src_filespec = search_recursively(path..subfolder_name.."\\")
         if src_filespec then
            return src_filespec
         end
      end
   end

   local src_filespec = search_recursively(src_folder:gsub("/", "\\"):gsub("\\*$", "\\"))
   if src_filespec then
      os.execute('copy /b "'..src_filespec..'" "'..dest_folder:gsub("/", "\\"):gsub("\\*$", "\\")..filename..'" 1>nul: 2>&1')
   end
end

-- find file.txt somewhere on drive C: and save it as D:\Found\file.txt
search_and_copy("file.txt", "C:\\", "D:\\Found")
```