# Lua Get all Folders/Files in lua

Tags: lua, io

Hey I am wondering if it is possibel to get all folder(s) and all files with a specific extension
like `.lua`

Example

```
source/**/shared/*.lua
```

But this is not working with `io.popen('dir "source/**/shared" /b /ad')` to list all folders in shared.

I don't know if is possibel
Thanks in advance
Neo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of directories in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303174/how-to-get-list-of-directories-in-lua)

Comment: "But this is not working with `io.popen('dir "source/**/shared" /b /ad')` to list all folders in shared." - *what* is not working? You have to read the output of the process opened with `io.popen` line by line.

Comment: @Péèlo - Asterisk and double-asterisk inside path does not work in Windows.  It's a feature from Linux.  On Windows, only the last level of path can contain asterisk.